# How to grant ownership of Files and Folders in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I came across a very anoying problem and it took me a while to solve it. Since 99% of the internet was telling me it was not possible and i could not find the answer on stackoverflow i decided to post it here.

I was trying to change the ownership of an folder/file in my windows machine. This is not much of a problem since DirectorySecurtiy has a nice function for it: "SetOwner()". I got this to work for my current account but i could not get it to work for someone else. Everytime i  tried to grant someone else ownership i got this error: “The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object”.

```
// Get folder or creates if not exists
DirectoryInfo dInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

// Get user
IdentityReference user = new NTAccount(username);

// Set owner
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.SetOwner(user);
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

So this code does work if i want to grant myself ownership but not if i want to grant someoneelse ownership. What to do?

Comment: Your program needs to run under an account with sufficient permissions to grant ownership.

Comment: It does, it ran as administator

Comment: Without explicitly enabling SeRestorePrivilege, we can only assign ownership to the current user or any of the user's groups for which the user is the owner (i.e. flagged `SE_GROUP_OWNER`). It's not enough to simply have SeRestorePrivilege in the user's token. It's not one of the privileges that the system enables automatically for us.

Comment: This is untrue, check the answer and use the uncpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the internet further I found the solution in this blog: https://fixingitpro.com/2011/07/08/set-owner-with-powershell-%E2%80%9Cthe-security-identifier-is-not-allowed-to-be-the-owner-of-this-object%E2%80%9D/

It is very strange and i dont know why but if you use unc pathing it will work.

> UNC names identify network resources using a specific notation. These names consist of three parts: a host device name, a share name, and an optional file path.
>   These three elements are combined using backslashes: \host-name\share-name\file_path

So what used to work for myself only: D:\{folderName} had to be: \\{IP or servername}\d$\{foldername}. If you test the exact same code agian only than with a different path it will work. Would be nice if someone could explain me why routing back to your own computer does work by a normal path does not.

Dont forget to run your application as administrator

Comment: I'm unable to replicate what that blogger's post showed, having used those cmdlets to change ACLs plenty.

Comment: Just use my original code and you will be able to change ownership. Its not about access controllist. Furthermore the blogger is talking about powershell but its the same for c#